# Blank Page when serving react build from node/express server in apache vps

Tags: reactjs, apache, express

I have an apache web-server that's running a node/express application server, and i will be using the express server to serve my static react files. When users go to the domain name, I have virtual host redirecting them to the express server.

```
    ServerName  subdomain.example.com
    ServerAlias www.subdomain.example.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://111.111.111.111:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://111.111.111.111:8080/
```

In the express server I have a catch all, that sends the index.html from the client when a non api-route is called.

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client')))
// ------- Routes -----------
const userRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const contactRoutes = require("./routes/contactRoutes");
const s3 = require("./routes/s3Routes")

// API route modules
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);
app.use("/api/contacts", contactRoutes);
app.use("/api/aws", s3);

app.use("*", (req, res) => {
  return res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'client',  'index.html'));
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// start node/express server on port and console log it
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on Port: ${port}`);
});
```

The express server is able to send the index.html from the client directory, but all i get is a blank page. I research and thought it could be solved by setting the homepage on the client `package.json` file, so i changed it to this

```
"homepage": "http://subdomain.example.com/var/www/example.com/sub_domains/contacts/client"
```

but this didn't work, and neither did `"homepage: '.'"` or `"homepage: '/var/www/example.com/sub_domains/contacts/client'"`

can anyone see what i'm doing wrong here? i'm assuming is the homepage attribute on the package.json file or the way that i'm sending the file from the express server, but not entirely sure.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after reading documentation a bit more, i found the solution. My problem was in the express server. I was using `path.resolve`, but in the official documentation they recommend using `path.join`. So doing that and setting the `"homepage: '.'"` on the client, is making everything work out